# R - How to use xtable to print a table() and keeping the row and column margin titles?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

I need to generate many small tables from pairs of vectors like this:

```
library(xtable)
input1 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
input2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,2)
result <- table(input1, input2)
xtable(result)
```

The console output is OK.

> result

```
       input2
input1 0 1 2
     0 3 0 0
     1 3 1 0
     2 2 1 1
```

But I'd like to get nice latex output instead.
xtable produces this code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
  \hline
 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  1 &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  2 &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

As you can see the "input1" and "input2" margin titles have dissapeared.
[image]

But I'd like to get something like this: (or with more lines if you think it looks nicer).
[image]

What command do I need to use in R in order to get it?

I've also tried with

```
 print(xtable(x), include.rownames=T, include.colnames=T, booktabs = TRUE)
```

But it doesn't make any difference. The problem is "xtable" removes the information.

P.S: I need that R creates a code like this: 
How can I do it?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|lll}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{input2}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}  &   0 &   1 &   2 \\  
    \cline{3-5}
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{input1}}  & 0 &   3 &   0 &   0 \\ 
  & 1 &   3 &   1 &   0 \\ 
  & 2 &   2 &   1 &   1 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Just change `print(xtable(format(ftable(result))), 
       include.rownames=FALSE, include.colnames=FALSE,
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) {gsub('"',"",x)})`

Comment: OK, thanks, but how can I get the left margin rotated? The way you suggest won't look nice whenever its title is too long.

Comment: @akrun I have updated my question with the latex code I need.  How can I generate it directly from R?